# Creating domains from specific values in table using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, dictionary

I have an `.sde` table that I'm trying to extract specific values from and create domains with them. The problem I'm running into is that there are multiple duplicate values in the table (which is fine, it's supposed to be like that due to different categories) and I'm only interested in the unique ones. I've created a dictionary `valueDict` which contains my domain names as the `value` and the application they're located in as the `key`. I then need to iterate over the values I'd like as my domains and insert them into their respective tables (the `value` from above).

Each application has a specific set of values that I'd like as domains. I'm also filtering the table to receive yet another specific view. I'm only printing the values below to see what I'm returning just for testing purposes.

In the example below, I'm getting back every value, including the duplicates.

```
...
InTable = "MyTable"
Fields = "DESCRIPTION", "TIME"

for key, value in valueDict.items():
    exp = "APPNAME = " + key + " and APR = 'EVENT'"
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(InTable, Fields, exp) as cursor:
        for i in cursor:
            print(key, value, i[0], i[1])
```

Comment: you can create keys with mulitple values by integrating lists, see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871492/how-can-you-get-a-python-dictionary-to-have-duplicate-keys-holding-values